# Showing that a Code is cyclic and finding the generator polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

Let $C\subset \mathbb{F}_3^3$ be a linear code with generator matrix $G=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$.

$(1)$ Find the standard form  for the generator matrix and the partiy check matrix.

Answer: $G=[I_2|P]=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2\\ 0 & 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ and thus $H=[-P^T|I_1]=\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 1 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix}$.

$(2)$ What is $d(C)$? [minimum distance of $C$]

Answer: I read online that it is the minimum number of linear dependent columns of the parity check matrix, that would be $d(C)=2$, right? Because of the second and third row being linearly dependent.

$(3)$ Show that $C$ is cyclic

Is there a way to show this using the matrices?

$(4)$ Find the generator and parity check polynomial of $C$.

$(5)$ Is $C$ a BCH-Code?

I have no attempts for $(4)$ and $(5)$ - any help would be nice!

Comment: About (3), you can use the fact that $C$ is cyclic if and only if its dual code $C^\perp$ is cyclic. This makes things easier in your case because $C^\perp$ is generated by the only row of $H$: $C^\perp=\left<(-2, 1, 1)\right>=\left<(1, 1, 1)\right>$, which is clearly cyclic.

Comment: In $\mathbb F_3$, $-1 = 2$ and $-2-=1$ the use of which might help a little with understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(4) The generator polynomial of a linear code $C$ in $\mathbb F_q^n$ is a divisor of $x^n-1$ and has degree $n-k$, where $k$ is the dimension of $C$ as a vector space over $\mathbb F_q$. In your case, $q=n=3$ and $k=2$, so the generator polynomial $g(x)$ you're looking for divides $x^3-1=(x-1)^3$ and has degree $1$. The only option is $g(x)=x-1$. The parity check polynomial then is $h(x)=\frac{x^n-1}{g(x)}=(x-1)^2$.

Comment: In cyclic code theory, it is generally assumed that $\gcd(q,n)=1$ which makes the theorems much more useful.   Since $q$ is a prime power, if $\gcd(q,n)>1$, the the gcd is necessarily of the form $p^m, m>0$, and the math requires many special cases etc.